# How to implement toggle checkbox in columns Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a requirement to implement a table of check boxes. Each column of check boxes behaves like a group so that only one of the boxes can be checked. [image]

Are there any good examples for implementing this knid of component using angular?

Comment: Probably not - I think you're on your own here. But from a usability standpoint, [uffda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uff_da). This looks somewhat like a punch card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very specific usecase, but quite easy to implement from scratch I think. Just store the state of the table (rows and cols) and the checked state for every column. On click verify that only one row of the column is checked. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkecae?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) is a short stackblitz example. You can use angular-material, bootstrap and an icon package for styling.

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  private numRows: number = 5;
  private numCols: number = 30;

  public grid: Array<Array<boolean>> = [];

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let row=0; row < this.numRows; row++) {
      this.grid.push([]);
      for (let col=0; col < this.numCols; col++) {
        this.grid[row].push(false);
      }
    }
  }

  onColumnClick(row: number, col: number) {
    this.grid.map((o, i) => {
      o[col] = i === row;
    })
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th *ngFor="let col of grid[0]; let i = index">{{ i }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of grid; let i = index">
    <td>2</td>
    <td *ngFor="let col of row; let i2 = index" (click)="onColumnClick(i, i2)">
      <div [class.checked]="col"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**app.component.css**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #eee;
}

.checked {
  background: #63c97e;
}
```

Comment: I'll upvote if you put the implementation in the answer instead of a link-only answer. The solution is nice, but code needs to be here.

Comment: Sure, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

1. have a look at Bootstrap and/or Angular powered Bootstrap. They should already have a checkbox group where only one option can be selected at a time. And you would need to customise that into a customised Bootstrap table.
2. Find a 3rd party Angular library that does this or similar things.
3. Write your own. (This should not be hard but controversial because some people don't wanna re-invent the wheel while some don't wanna have a 3rd party to control part of their own code.)